how to fix a threading problem in python for a socket server code
i'm trying to build a Trivia game in socket python but i'm facing a problem that when multiple clients try to submit their answers to the server the server most of the time doesn't accept all the answers of the clients which causes a scoring issue in the game here's  the function that for handelling the clients answers and i believe is making the problem :
def handle_client_answers(server_socket, question, correct_answer):
    """Handle answers for the current question."""
    start_time = time.time()
    first_correct_time = None

    def process_answer(data, addr):
        """Process a single client's answer."""
        nonlocal first_correct_time  # Allow modification of the shared variable
        answer = data.decode().strip()
        with lock:
            if addr not in clients or clients[addr]["answered"]:
                return
            
            clients[addr]["answered"] = True

            server_socket.sendto(f"Answer Submitted: {answer}".encode(), addr)
            if answer.lower() == correct_answer.lower():
                if not first_correct_time:
                    first_correct_time = time.time()
                    clients[addr]["score"] += 10  # Full points for first correct answer
                else:
                    time_diff = time.time() - first_correct_time
                    score_multiplier = max(0.5, 1 - time_diff / 10)  # Decrease score for slower answers
                    clients[addr]["score"] += int(10 * score_multiplier)
                server_socket.sendto("Correct!".encode(), addr)
                print(f"Received answer from {clients[addr]['username']} ({addr}): {answer} - Correct!")
            else:
                server_socket.sendto("Wrong answer.".encode(), addr)
                print(f"Received answer from {clients[addr]['username']} ({addr}): {answer} - Incorrect!")


    while time.time() - start_time < 30:
        try:
            data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            # Start a thread to process this answer
            threading.Thread(target=process_answer, args=(data, addr), daemon=True).start()

            # Exit early if all clients have answered
            with lock:
                if all(client["answered"] for client in clients.values()):
                    break
        except socket.timeout:
            continue
    time.sleep(2)


i tried asking ChatGPT to solve the problem and it intreduced a solution using a queue:
from queue import Queue

answer_queue = Queue()  # Queue to hold incoming answers

def handle_client_answers(server_socket, question, correct_answer):
    """Handle answers for the current question."""
    start_time = time.time()
    first_correct_time = None

    def enqueue_answer(data, addr):
        """Add the answer to the processing queue."""
        answer_queue.put((data, addr))

    def process_answers():
        """Continuously process answers from the queue."""
        nonlocal first_correct_time
        while time.time() - start_time < 30 or not answer_queue.empty():
            try:
                data, addr = answer_queue.get(timeout=1)  # Wait for answers from the queue
                process_answer(data, addr)  # Process the answer
            except Exception as e:
                continue  # Handle timeouts or empty queue gracefully

    def process_answer(data, addr):
        """Process a single client's answer."""
        nonlocal first_correct_time  # Allow modification of the shared variable
        answer = data.decode().strip()
        with lock:
            if addr not in clients or clients[addr]["answered"]:
                return
            
            clients[addr]["answered"] = True

            server_socket.sendto(f"Answer Submitted: {answer}".encode(), addr)
            if answer.lower() == correct_answer.lower():
                if not first_correct_time:
                    first_correct_time = time.time()
                    clients[addr]["score"] += 10  # Full points for first correct answer
                else:
                    time_diff = time.time() - first_correct_time
                    score_multiplier = max(0.5, 1 - time_diff / 10)  # Decrease score for slower answers
                    clients[addr]["score"] += int(10 * score_multiplier)
                server_socket.sendto("Correct!".encode(), addr)
                print(f"Received answer from {clients[addr]['username']} ({addr}): {answer} - Correct!")
            else:
                server_socket.sendto("Wrong answer.".encode(), addr)
                print(f"Received answer from {clients[addr]['username']} ({addr}): {answer} - Incorrect!")

    # Start the worker thread to process answers from the queue
    threading.Thread(target=process_answers, daemon=True).start()

    # Collect answers during the question period
    while time.time() - start_time < 30:
        try:
            data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            enqueue_answer(data, addr)  # Add the answer to the queue
        except socket.timeout:
            continue

    time.sleep(2)

but the problem remained the same
to access the full code please visit this github :https://github.com/moe-the-goat/1st-network-project

if anyone needs the full server code to understand the problem clearly i can provide it

How do you call handle_client_answers(...)? And where does server_socket come from?

in this github you can see the full code for the server and client
https://github.com/moe-the-goat/1st-network-project

simplify your code using this ThreadingTCPServer template https://stackoverflow.com/a/61918942/4534316

Please simplify your code to provide a [mcve], not an offsite link. We aren’t going to debug your full code for you. Narrow it down to a specific problem by removing all unnecessary code and still produce the problem.
